# Bigquery denomalization

Tags: google-bigquery

In Google Bigquery (or a similar database), what's the appropriate balance between denormalizing data and not repeating data?

For example, we have `table_1` with columns

- date
- value A
- value B

And another `table_2` with columns

- date
- value B
- value C

`table_1` is about 10 000x larger than `table_2`, and so making a table with all three columns would duplicate a lot of data. And `table_2` is used in a few other circumstances, so may make sense to keep separate

Thanks for any insight

What's the best way to think about this?

Comment: Did you did a cost wise comparison on these? Remember currently $20 equals 1TB of data on BigQuery. I feel storage is so cheap nowadays than we don't think on this, simply we reuse the data as many times as we need.

Comment: It's more of a data management issue that a cost issue. You're exactly right that storage is so cheap now. My concern is that the massive multiplication of data will be difficult to manage from a loading & maintenance POV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the implication of denormalising your data is a outrageous increase in storage cost (which is unlikely) you are better of completely denormalising it.

Bigquery will probably perform faster and queries will be easier to set up. There is little benefit in trying to minimise the amount of stored data and you pay a cost in query time and query cost when you need to join the tables up again.

If you have a mix of tables with some big and some small and you don't always need to refer to the large tables for queries, there may be practical benefits in keeping the tables separate and it may reduce query costs.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that table1 is 10000x larger than table2, I would not denormalise the data. You would pay 10000x more for running a query with only data from table 2.

To take the decision, I would analyse how often queries joining column C with A are to know if the cost of denormalisation pays off. Joins are expensive in BigQuery but still affordable if they do not happen frequently.